# Can I define a shorthand for tuples in C#

Tags: c#, tuples, valuetuple

The following function takes an object as a parameter, the object is actually a tuple and is cast as such:

```
private void MyFunction(object clientWithThreadIDAsObject)
{
    (TcpClient m_sender, int m_nListenerThreadID) clientWithThreadID = ((TcpClient m_sender, int m_nListenerThreadID))clientWithThreadIDAsObject;
```

Here is the function being called from elsewhere in the code:

```
(TcpClient m_sender, int m_nListenerThreadID) ClientWithThreadID = (sender, m_nNextListenerThreadID);
                    
MyFunction(ClientWithThreadID);
```

So the text `(TcpClient m_sender, int m_nListenerThreadID)` has been written three times.

Is it possible to somehow define a shorthand for this? (Like a macro in c).

Some way to not have to type `(TcpClient m_sender, int m_nListenerThreadID)` every time it is needed?

Comment: You can define a class encapsulating the tuple and pass it as the parameter

Comment: Best bet here is to define a record: `public sealed record TcpTransfer(TcpClient Sender, int ListenerId);` and use that instead of a tuple. For such a small type you might even want to make it a readonly record struct:  `public readonly record struct TcpTransfer(TcpClient Sender, int ListenerId);`

Comment: In two of the three places, it was not actually needed: you could just use `var` instead. Only the cast requires writing the tuple definition.

Comment: Why this method takes  `object` if it immediately casts it to that tuple?

Comment: A small demonstration of M Kloster's comment: [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fVIdEN)